# DT::datatable on grouped dataframe within Rmarkdown report (HTML)

Tags: javascript, r, button, group-by, dt

I have a grouped data frame output that I want to visualize as a DT::datatable with Download buttons (csv,excel) in Rmarkdown report (HTML).

It works fine when I'm constructing the Rmarkdown, but shows an error saying that there is no group by method applicable for object classes datatable and htmlwidgets.

Many Thanks in advance.

Here is my Code :

```
## Grouping columns

Site <- LETTERS[1:6]
Block <- LETTERS[1:4] ## For each Site
Plot <- paste(rep("P",10),seq(1,10,1),sep="_") ## For each Block 
df <- expand.grid(Site = Site, Block = Block, Plot = Plot)

## Dependant variables

df <-cbind.data.frame(df,data.frame(Tmin=runif(min=-3,max=18,n=240),
                         Tmax=runif(min=10,max=39, n=240),
                                    Index1=runif(0,5,n=240),
                                    Index2=runif(1,10,n=240)))

# Export grouped df as datatable
library(dplyr)


df%>%
  group_by(Site,Block,Plot)%>%
  summarize(Tmin_avg=mean(Tmin), Tmax_avg=mean(Tmax))%>%
  DT::datatable(
   extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = 
      list('copy', 'print', list(
        extend = 'collection',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
        text = 'Download'
      ))
   ))
```

Comment: dplyr::group_by is used to summarise and aggregate data. You have not aggregated anything in your example. Did you perhaps mean to do so?

Comment: Indeed! I have edited the code, I just fogot to mention it.

Comment: Please add that dependency too (library(tidyverse) or library(dplyr)) so that others can run your example. And remove ... from summarize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to aggregate your data and you should remove the `...` from summarize function. The `...` are used inside functions to give the user flexibility to add existing parameters to functions. E.g.

```
library(tidyverse) 

aggfun <- function(df, ...) {
  df%>%
    group_by(Site,Block,Plot)%>%
    summarize(Tmin_avg=mean(Tmin), Tmax_avg=mean(Tmax), ...)%>%
    DT::datatable(
      extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = 
          list('copy', 'print', list(
            extend = 'collection',
            buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
            text = 'Download'
          ))
      ))
}

aggfun(df, T_min = min(Tmin))
```

Your example works if you do the changes:

```
df%>%
  group_by(Site,Block,Plot)%>%
  summarize(Tmin_avg=mean(Tmin), Tmax_avg=mean(Tmax))%>%
  DT::datatable(
   extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = 
      list('copy', 'print', list(
        extend = 'collection',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
        text = 'Download'
      ))
   ))
```

Comment: It s working , Many thanks.  I d like to mention that the "..." were added to say implicitly that multiple aggregations happen within the summarize function for multiple variables.